# Issues with Logitech K400 plus in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, logitech

I have a Logitech K400 plus wireless keyboard with integrated touchpad.

Ubuntu 16.04 recognizes it out of the box and it is correctly paired (uses Logitech Unifying Receiver). However, very often, when using the touchpad the cursor freezes for a second and then jumps to a different position and freezes again and jumps again, making it uncontrolable. The same happens with the keyboard, you are writing, it freezes and suddenly all the letters appear. Turning off/on the keyboard fixes the issue in some cases, but not always.

Sometimes it works fine without this behaviour, but the issues appear very often and it is really frustrating.

Any idea on how to fix this issue?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my english.

G.

Answer (score 2):

I have had various problems with a [Logitech K400](https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400-plus) Plus on in Ubuntu 16.04.

Installing "[Solaar](https://pwr.github.io/Solaar/)" from the Ubuntu Software, Un-pairing and then Re-pairing the keyboard (I was prompted to switch off and then switch on the keyboard again during the process) seemed to improve matters.