# How To Replace Logitech Wireless Unified USB Plug In Ubuntu

Tags: usb, keyboard, logitech

I have a logitech k400r wireless keyboard with unified wireless USB plug. I lost the USB plug, but I have a new unified wireless plug from a logitech 400+ keyboard, however, the keyboard is not responding. I was under the impression that a unified plug should work with any keyboard that support unified receiver. How do i make it work with the new receiver? (I am using Ubuntu 17.04)

[image][image]
(Notice the unified support on both reciever and keyboard...)

It seams Logitech does have some software for this purpose for Windows, Mac Os and Chrome OS, but not Linux: http://support.logitech.com/en_us/software/unifying

Comment: Maybe?  https://askubuntu.com/a/809608/231142  Can be installed via terminal with `sudo apt install solaar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either:

- Using Windows and the `Logitech Keyboard/Mouse`, and `Unifying Software`, you need to pair the USB dongle and the K400r keyboard. Once paired, it'll then work in Ubuntu.
- In Ubuntu, install `solaar` and it'll do the pairing, and some limited configuration. More information about `solaar`, and software downloads, can be seen at [their GitHub repo page](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar).

To install `solaar` from the Ubuntu repos, in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solaar
```

Then follow the [Solaar usage guide](https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/usage).

You should also make sure that the firmware in the USB dongle is current. See [this link](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-gb/articles/360035037273-Firmware-Update-Tool) for instructions and the firmware.